# Responsive arrow between two tables

Tags: jquery, css

**edited as per the comments**

Need to display an arrow (responsively) in between two tables on click of each row from left side table

Got this link while searching

http://jsfiddle.net/43dmvvto/3/

so using that made small changes as shown below

```
<html>
<style>
  #output {position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 14px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
  border-left: 14px solid yellow;
  };
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
    <table id="mTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sieve"    >
        <thead><th >Name</th><th >Department</th></thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
          <td ><span style="cursor:default"><a  id="showdata"  class="datalink" detail="Cell: #emp_cell# ">    #emp_namefirst#</td>
          <td >#dept_name# </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td ><span style="cursor:default"><a  id="showdata"  class="datalink" detail="Cell: #emp_cell# ">    #emp_namefirst#</td>
          <td >#dept_name# </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td ><span style="cursor:default"><a  id="showdata"  class="datalink" detail="Cell: #emp_cell# ">    #emp_namefirst#</td>
          <td >#dept_name# </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 ">
   <table id="mTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sieve"    >
      <thead><th >Name</th><th >Department</th></thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td ><span style="cursor:default"><a  id="showdata"  class="datalink" detail="Cell: #emp_cell# ">    #emp_namefirst#</td>
        <td >#dept_name# </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td ><span style="cursor:default"><a  id="showdata"  class="datalink" detail="Cell: #emp_cell# ">    #emp_namefirst#</td>
        <td >#dept_name# </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td ><span style="cursor:default"><a  id="showdata"  class="datalink" detail="Cell: #emp_cell# ">    #emp_namefirst#</td>
        <td >#dept_name# </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
   <div id="output"></div>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
         $('a.datalink').click(function () {  
            $('#output').css('top',$(this).offset().top);
            $('#output').css('left',($(this).offset().left + parseInt($("#mTable").css('width'))));
            $("#output").css('visibility','visible');
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Everything is as expected except the responsiveness, Arrow is getting displayed on click of tr, how to make arrow responsive? as of now its position is fixed

[Bigger screen result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMdYo.jpg)
[Smaller screen result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhKsJ.jpg)

Comment: I don’t see any arrows in your fiddle. Also, no one here know what this `<cfloop query="Corporate"  >` stuff is actually outputting. You want to discuss a client-side problem here, so show client-side code, and not something that renders on the server.

Comment: using that jsfiddle link I have coded and pasted the whole html

Comment: Stuff like `<cfloop query="Corporate"  ><cfoutput>` is not HTML, that is most likely part of some server-side templating language. And, again - what “arrow” are you talking about to begin with? There is no arrow anywhere in what your fiddle shows.

Comment: I have used that fiddle as reference, the html code which I have pasted is the thing which I am referring to, Apologies if I am confusing!!

Comment: Then please set up a fiddle, or make the above code into a testable code snippet, so that people can easily check on what you mean.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/qAcplvdn8ZhJkUAzTzTL?p=preview
Above is the url, If user clicks on left table row, triangle appears in between the tables, its just to show the user which row as been clicked. It appears fine in big screens, but checked with shrinking the screen triangle is not responsive its position is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CSS Pseudo-classes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) to display the arrow on each row on click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.datalink').click(function() {
$(this).closest('tr').addClass('active').siblings('tr').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
tr.active:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 14px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
  border-left: 14px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">

    <table id="mTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sieve">
      <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Department</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><span style="cursor:default"><a  id="showdata"  class="datalink" detail="Cell: #emp_cell# ">#emp_namefirst#</a></span></td>
          <td>#dept_name# </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span style="cursor:default"><a  id="showdata"  class="datalink" detail="Cell: #emp_cell# ">#emp_namefirst#</a></span></td>
          <td>#dept_name# </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span style="cursor:default"><a  id="showdata"  class="datalink" detail="Cell: #emp_cell# ">    #emp_namefirst#</a></span></td>
          <td>#dept_name# </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 ">
    <table id="mTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sieve">
      <tr>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>Grade</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><span style="cursor:default"> 123456789</span></td>
          <td>A </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span style="cursor:default"> 123456789</span></td>
          <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span style="cursor:default"> 123456789</span></td>
          <td>C </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try using this answer ?